# MongoDB : how to put conditional for multiple optional value

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

How to apply multi condition in mongoDB find condition with same key name??

I have collection in MongoDB:

```
[{
    'name': 'test1',
    'brand': 'A'
}, {
    'name': 'test2',
    'brand': 'B'
}, {
    'name': 'test3',
    'brand': 'C'
}, {
    'name': 'test4',
    'brand': 'D'
}]
```

**server.js**

```
app.get('/products', function(request, response) {
    // request.query => {'brand': 'A', 'brand: 'B', 'brand': 'C'}
    mongoose.model('products').find(request.query, function(err, data) {
        response.json(data);
        // data shoule be matching only if 'brand': 'A' or 'brand': 'B' or brand: 'C'
    });
});
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: The input here `{'brand': 'A', 'brand: 'B', 'brand': 'C'}` and would be interpretted as just `{ 'brand': 'C' }` since JSON and JavaScript objects can only have a single value per key. You probably want `{ 'brand': [ 'A','B','C' ] }` to begin with. And that basically points to how to do this in the full answer

Comment: You might also then understand how the answer you accepted is not a solution to this then. You cannot iterate "keys" for an object that essentially has "one" key only otherwise your logic will fail. That was the point I was making here.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to create the query object using [`$or` operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/), like this:

```
var query = { $or: [] };
for (key in req.query)
    query.$or.push({ key: request.query[key] });
//=> { $or: [ {brand: 'A'}, {brand: 'B'},  …] }
```

Then use that as your query

```
Model.find(query, function(err, data){
    res.json(data);
});
```